# iTerm 2 sometimes can correct `ls` only after `cd` to somewhere and back

Tags: iterm2

Illustration of problem:

```
$ ls
$ cd .. && cd -
$ ls
file1.txt file2.txt
```

gif:

[image: iterm2 bug with ls]

I facing with this situation when another program created files in this directory and when I am `cd` to here before creating of this files.

Some kind of cache? How to fix it?
Build 3.0.4, iMac El Capital, local file system.

Comment: How about if you use `ls ./`? Same behaviour?

Comment: @jwpfox yes the same

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Is that a normal directory or something special ?

Comment: @sel-fish git-directory, I did not notice this problem for non-git.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich can you share more details? such as how you produce ```file1.txt```

Comment: @sel-fish I am developing program in Python that download some files from web - only this case, this is computer at work. Sometimes I see that even after exit my program after `ls` I see nothing, my first thought - oh I need to `cd` to somewhere and go back. I just now tried manually create folder through Finder and do `ls` - it is ok I see my new folder.

Comment: @sel-fish I found the same behaviour for default Terminal app, so looks like problem somewhere in OS...

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich nice attempt. can you try to run your project in a linux vm ?

Comment: @sel-fish I run tests for my project at another PC with Linux and yes, the problem was because my program remove folder where I am in terminal (`Terminator` today) and create again - but inside this recreated folder `ls` not working and I again need to exit & enter to this folder. I checked this case manually too. So maybe you know some workaround for this?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich what about return err when you try to  ```ls``` in the stale dir ?

Comment: @sel-fish what do you mean?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich you're in a ```stale``` dir which is already deleted and re-created. i don't know how to work around, but my ```zsh``` will warn me when i'm in such situation.

Comment: @sel-fish ok we found the root of the problem, if you write this as answer I can accept this :)

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich you got the answer yourself, it's better that you write it down and accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @sel-fish for good questions: this is correct behaviour to Mac & Linux (I tested in Ubuntu) - when folder was removed and recreated with the same name - for Bash this is not the same folder. You can read more about this (and find possible solutions) here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203467/ls-error-when-directory-is-deleted

https://superuser.com/questions/702402/how-do-i-refresh-directory-in-bash

Also I created [bug-report](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/5117) for this behaviour in iTerm2 - I hope developers will implement some workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is still a bug as of Oct, 2022, here is a temporary solution that lessens the work to be done.

Use the below command.

```
cd `pwd`
```

This command will execute the `pwd` command inside the backticks first and then pass it as an argument to `cd` which would make it come to the same directory. A *refresh* of some sort.